# First value of a char array in c is coming back as int?

Tags: c, arrays

I do not understand what I am doing wrong here, I am trying to convert a string that is coded in Hex to binary, but when I try to access the first value of the string to start decoding, I am getting errors because it comes back as an int instead. Forgive me as I am inexperienced using C.

```
...
char hex[256] = "746573743d31";
printf("%s", hex[0]);
...
```

Literally just trying to print the first value of the string here as an example so that I know my logic is right, and I get:

**
warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
**

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. `%s` needs a `char *`. You gave it `hex[0]` which is a `char` and gets promoted to an `int`. Use `%c` to print a character.

Comment: Advice: Next time you have an error, fire up your google fu and paste the exact error message into the search bar.

Answer (score 1):

So by specifying `hex[0]` you are only passing only the first character.  That is: `printf("%s", '7')`.

If you are trying to print the string: `printf("%s", hex);`

If you are really trying to print the first character: `printf("%c", hex[0]);`